# How to stop fread from displaying messages when it is inside trycatch

Tags: r, data.table

I want to make a function that loads a csv file if it exists and builds it using a database connection otherwise. I thought of using trycatch and then fread inside as follows:

```
library(data.table)
res <- tryCatch({fread(input="filename.csv",sep=";");},
   error = function(err){return("error")} ,
   warning = function(war){return("error")} ,silent=TRUE)

if("character" %in% class(res)){print("Build the file anew")}
```

I want this to be silent, i.e., not display any messages. However I get:

```
Der Befehl "filename.csv" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder konnte nicht gefunden werden.
```

(appologies for the German) and only afterwards the `if` part runs. Is there a way to suppress this message?

Comment: Works for me, what versions of `R` and `data.table` do you use?

Comment: R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18) -- "World-Famous Astronaut"
Copyright (C) 2015 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)   

And data.table: data.table 1.9.4  For help type: ?data.table
*** NB: by=.EACHI is now explicit. See README to restore previous behaviour.  

(And thanks for the edits to the question :))

Comment: OK, I have updated data.table and now it works. I did not know that there was a newer version because the RStudio "check for package updates" apparently does not show all the packages. So I have used update.packages() instead.

Comment: RStudio update should update everything. I guess your RStudio looks at a mirror that is not up to date yet. v1.9.6 was released only a few days ago.

Comment: you did catch error and warning but not messages, use `suppressMessages` or `withCallingHandlers` to catch messages keeping the returned value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it, and with `data.table` 1.9.4 I got:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

(Which I guess is the executive summary of your long German sentence ;) )

With `data.table` version 1.9.6 it works as expected. So just update your packages:

```
update.packages()
```

And you should be fine.